# Is there an efficient way to scrape substrings from column values in Postgres?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a column called user_response, on which I want to do variety of operations like take out words contained in quotes, and take out the part of the string after colon (:)

One such operation is this:
Let's say for a record

```
user_response = "My company: 'XYZ Co.' has allowed to use:: the following \n \n kind of product: RealMadridTShirts"
```

Now, I want to scrape the part of the string after last colon(:). Hence, my output should be RealMadridTShirts

I could achieve this somehow with the following hack:

```
SELECT reverse(split_part(reverse(user_response), ' :', 1))
```

However, this is grossly inefficient, specially when I am having to do this over 500,000 rows. It's not an operation that I will doing throughout the day. This operation is for a once-a-day load but even then the load is becoming very expensive.

Coming from Oracle, I know I could have used INSTR and SUBSTR functions to achieve it in a more elegant fashion (without having to reverse the string and all.

Also, what if I had to scrape the text after the second last colon?

Comment: It will always be inefficient, since you'll have to plow through 500K rows. regexp_replace() might be your friend.

Comment: Atleast, I can better. The fact that I am having to reverse the string twice for each record itself is painful. Instead, I should be able to use position()/INSTR() to get position of a character by specifying a *particular occurrence*

Comment: It does look like a "find the next occurrence of str/char x after position y" function would be useful to add to core. Patches are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the string after the last colon, right?

> My company: 'XYZ Co.' has allowed to use:: the following \n \n kind of product: RealMadridTShirts

It's trivial with a regular expression:

```
regress=> SELECT (regexp_matches(
                      'My company: ''XYZ Co.'' has allowed to use:: the following \n \n kind of product: RealMadridTShirts',
                      '.*:(.*?)$')
                 )[1];
   regexp_matches   
--------------------
  RealMadridTShirts
(1 row)
```

The apparent lack of a function to request the position of a string counting from a particular starting point makes it harder to do without using a regexp, but as a regexp is sure to be the fastest way to solve this I doubt that's an issue.

Your bigger problem is likely to be that you're scanning so much data. That's never going to be fast.

Comment: I tried this on my column name:
SELECT (regexp_matches(
                      user_response,
                      '.*:(.*?)$')
                 )[1]
FROM table_name;
I got an error saying that user_response doesn't exist

Comment: @user3422637 I'd need to see the schema (table definition) to comment usefully about that.

Comment: Got it. The column was of text data type. I needed to cast it to varchar to make regexp_matches work